# Student Marks Apps using Flutter and Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to develop a app to store student marks.
And I'm using firestore database to store that data.
I created two collections **student_info** and **subject_info**
In *student_info* collection there are 5 student documents and they have 3 fields **student_id, name, active_status** and in *subject_info* collection there are 3 subject documents and they have 2 fields **subject_id, subject**.
How do I connect these two and add their marks?
I'm using flutter.
Thank you!

Comment: use document id as keys to map , then use the document id to get the details

Comment: did not get you question please share code snippet and your firebase collection screenshot for reference.

Comment: Please update more details of the code and what you are actually trying to implement.
Also add screenshot and documents if you have any.